# columns with same name but other with calculated one Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, duplicates

I have data in database like

```
1     CP     12
2     OB     8
1     CP     19
3     AB     22
2     OB     33
1     CP     19
3     AB     22
```

What I want after running query on it

```
2     OB     41
1     CP     60
3     AB     44
```

What I tried

```
 var abc = db.OilVolumes.GroupBy(x => new { x.OilType.OilTypeName, x.Weight }).Select(y => new 
{
oilType = y.Key.OilTypeName,
weight = y.Sum(z => z.Weight)
});
```

But I failed... Give me a in similar format

Thanks

Comment: Explain what the logic is for the data transformation.

Comment: Typo? `2  OB 41`, not  63

Comment: I want to fetch oil volume from table. colomn 2 is oil type i do not want repetition of oil type. Moreover i want to calculate all volume from all rows for each type respectively.

Comment: 3rd row is weight.. I want total weight of each type and to not be repeated. only one row have one oil type and all of its weight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number and the name seem redundant, so I skipped the number. I assume you have a class like this:

```
public class OilVolume
{
    public int Volume { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public OilVolume(string name, int value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Volume = value;
    }

    public override string ToString(){
        return $"{Name} {Volume}";
    }
}
```

Then the query for your desired output would be:

```
var oilSums = db.OilVolumes
  .GroupBy(oil => oil.Name)
  .Select(group => new OilVolume(group.Key,  group.Sum(oil => oil.Volume)))
  .OrderByDescending(oil => oil.Volume);
```

and the output of

```
foreach (var oil in oilSums)
 Console.WriteLine(oil);
```

is

```
CP 50
AB 44
OB 41
```

I assume the `CP 60`in your example is a mistake?

Comment: Hey thanks here... Actually i have data in database. Where i have data in rows. Like in TYPE1 oil have 10 rows and again TYPE2 have 5 etc.
 want data through link so that i get output like 
TYPE1     40
TYPE2     50

Comment: Ok, you should be able to transfer my example to work with a `DataRow` Your initial post wasn't very specific. Nevertheless I would recommend to map your database data to some type of object and then use the approach I gave here.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `x.Weight` from your `GroupBy`

```
var abc = db.OilVolumes.GroupBy(x => new { x.OilType.OilTypeName }).Select(y => new 
    {
     oilType = y.Key.OilTypeName,
     weight = y.Sum(z => z.Weight)
    });
```